# ReactJS onClick function does not work, TypeError: this is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I try to learn `React` but seems in the new version there are some changes:

```
class Reactapp extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    sayMassage(){
        console.log(this.props.children);
    }

    render(){
        var sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);
        return(
            <div>
                <h3> Hello {this.props.word}</h3>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.sayMassage}>
                        Click Me
                    </a>
                </p>;
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Reactapp word="React">This is a ReactJS 15.5  Tutorial</Reactapp>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This code should work but seems I am missing something.
It should `console.log` "This is a ReactJS 15.5  Tutorial"
`super` is called before this so this could not be `null`.

I tried to `bind this` but I don't know how, My code seems to fail. The old code with `createReactClass` had `auto-binding` tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a scope issue, just write this line in the constructor, it will work:

```
this.sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);
```

And remove this one:

```
var sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);
```

Check the working example:

```js
class Reactapp extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);
    }
    
    sayMassage(){
      console.log(this.props.children);
    }

    render(){
      
      return(
         <div>
            <h3> Hello {this.props.word}</h3>
            <p>
               <a href="#" onClick={this.sayMassage}>
                  Click Me
               </a>
            </p>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
      <Reactapp word="React">This is a ReactJS 15.5  Tutorial</Reactapp>,
      document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I understand the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Mayank said, but there is another way - using arrow functions. That way, the function will automatically take 'this' of the class instance.

It will be something like the below. You will have to remove the binding that you did originally, of course.

```
class Reactapp extends React.Component{

sayMassage = () => {
  console.log(this.props.children);
}

render(){

  return(
<div>
<h3> Hello {this.props.word}</h3>
<p><a href="#" onClick={this.sayMassage}>Click Me</a></p>;
</div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <Reactapp word="React">This is a ReactJS 15.5  Tutorial</Reactapp>
</div>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

P.S. There is a typo in the function name, `sayMassage` (should be `sayMessage`), unless you actually wanted to say Massage :-)

Comment: Thanks mate. it worked, and i misstyped It is indeed Message :) not Massage

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your line `var sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);`

It has to be in the `constructor`, like this :

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);
}
```

Or, to keep the context when calling your `function` and not having to `bind`, you can use an `arrow function` in the link, like this :

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => this.sayMassage}>Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve your scoping problem is to move the binding to the class constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {...};

this.sayThaiMassage = this.sayThaiMassage.bind(this);
```

}

or using a fat arrow function like so:

```
myFatGreekMassage = (event ) => {
  ...your code
}
```

While fat arrows functions keeping the scope (this is that) your problem is also solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onClick={() => ::this.sayMassage}`

And remove `var sayMassage = this.sayMassage.bind(this);`

--

`::` here make the bind this with the current scope.

`() =>` the arrow function declare a function which will be executed when you click on the element. If you don't declare the call as a function it will be executed every time you reload the page, without action needed.